# subscribing to @Output event emitter in constructor - is it safe not to unsubscribe?

Tags: angular

subscribing to @Output event emitter in component constructor - is it safe not to unsubscribe?

My intuation says that the EventEmitter dies when the component dies hence all the subscribers are freed as well am i right?

Comment: Are you subscribing to yourself? Can you share code?

Answer (score 0):

Event emitters shares the same lifecycle of the component. But in general, it is a good practice to unsubscribe the event emitters on the ngOnDestroy() method, to avoid any unwanted getting event emitted.